# helm - convert yaml file content to json

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to use and convert a YAML file to JSON in k8s helm template. The template looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-file
data:
  sounds.json: |-
{{ .Files.Get "file/sounds.yaml" | toPrettyJson | indent 4 }}
```

and the `file/sounds.yaml` is:

```yaml
animal:
  dog:
    sound: bark
  cat:
    sound: meow
  sheep:
    sound: baa
```

The outcome from `helm template` command is:

```bash
$ helm template release-name chart-name
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-file
data:
  sounds.json: |-
    "animal:\n  dog:\n    sound: bark\n  cat:\n    sound: meow\n  sheep:\n    sound: baa\n"
```

but I want the result to be:

```bash
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-value
data:
  sounds.json: |-
    {
      "animal": {
        "cat": {
          "sound": "meow"
        },
        "dog": {
          "sound": "bark"
        },
        "sheep": {
          "sound": "baa"
        }
      }
    }
```

If I use `.Values` instead of `.Files` I am able to get the same result but my need is to do with `.Files` only. Is there any function or something by which I can achieve the expected result?

Comment: I think you need to parse the incoming yaml file, just pipe it into `fromYaml` before `toPrettyJson`:
`{{ .Files.Get "file/sounds.yaml" | fromYaml | toPrettyJson | indent 4 }}`

Answer (score 0):

As **[Marcos Toledo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8286172/marcos-toledo)** suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460010/helm-convert-yaml-file-content-to-json#comment133141894_75460010) using `fromYaml` before `toPrettyJson` worked for me.